# .NET Core StartUp.cs not working - my console app stops automatically

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, frameworks

I am using Windows 10 64-bit and Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 with .NET Core SDK. I am new in .NET Core. I am using the .NET Standard 1.6 framework.
I want to know how to run the .NET Core application with a startup class.

Kindly check below point which I follow this to start application:

First add runtimes in project.json

```
"runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },
```

Then add the Program.cs with the void main function.
Console is not working properly while build this project: always asks please Restore package again in reference files.

Add buildOptions in project.json

```
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "debugType": "portable",
    "embed": {
      "include": [ "Resource.resx" ]
    }
}
```

Add dependency in project.json

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    }
```

When I debug the Console app it runs and stops automatically even when I check StartUp.cs file with InitializeAsync() method; I'm not able to debug this method.

Comment: What is your WebHostBuilder configuration like?

Comment: If you're just starting off in .NET Core, any reason you don't go straight to the full GA SDK release (using csproj) instead of using project.json? You'll need Visual Studio 2017 instead of Visual Studio 2015...

Comment: Actually I am new in core so I don't know how to check webHostBulider configuration.

Comment: did you run dotnet restore? Or maybe it's not necessary from Visual Studio?

Comment: @Pankil Show code in Program.Main method. Also Agree, should be using VS 2017.. project.json is deprecated.

Comment: @DávidMolnár yes i restored..

Comment: @JuanCarlos My debug point is not going into main method.. and let me try on VS 2017.

Comment: So what's the actual problem? It does not build, it does not stop on a breakpoint? I don't understand...

Comment: @JonSkeet is this definitely run in VS 2017.

Comment: @DávidMolnár It it build successfully. yes i am not able to find starting point of this console application even I put all the breakpoint in startUp.cs, program.cs, ApplicationDomain.cs. 
so, I want to know how to debug this core application

Comment: also I don't Understand why this is not supported in netcoreapp1.6

"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    }

Comment: Seeing as all you've provided are bits of project.json, which isn't supported on VS2017, then no, it wouldn't work on VS2017. You'd use a csproj project file instead.

Comment: Hello All,
I find the solution.. Need to Change the Framework netstandard1.6 to netcoreapp1.6..
So it will works to go into the program.cs main method.

Thanks for support.
Thank you so much.